# Deriving a Big O notation by Algorithm time-complexity analysis

Tags: algorithm, big-o, computer-science

```
int m(int i)                                                                                     
{
if (i==1)                                                                                     
    return i;                                                                                 
else                                                                                            
    return m(i-1) + m(i-1)；                                                     
        }
```

I did the following:
Lines 3 and 4 counts for 1 each. I have no idea for calculating the number of times line 5 & 6 will be checked. Since it is recurrsive how can I  to derive the big O notation?

Comment: checkout Master theorem, it is used to determine the time complexity for a recursion.

Answer (score 3):

You may understand this best perhaps by just writing out on a piece of paper what the function calls look like for some small input, say `i == 3`:

```
            m(3)
       /           \
    m(2)           m(2)
  /      \       /      \
m(1)     m(1)  m(1)     m(1)
```

It should be clear that at each level, the number of function calls doubles.  This is exponential behavior, and so the complexity is roughly `O(2^n)`, where `n` is the input value.

Comment: What will be the number of times each statement will be checked in the form of  exponential behavior?

Comment: You call `m(2)`, there are 3 evaluations.  You call `m(3)`, there are 7 evaluations.

Comment: In computer science that's indeed exponential. In programming, however, and depending on language, the compiler may be allowed to optimize `m(i-1) + m(i-1)` to [`2 * m(i-1)`](https://godbolt.org/z/z5h87f) which makes it linear. Or, conceivably, even `1 << (i - 1)` for constant time.

Comment: @dxiv Of course, if you want to go down that road, we can consider using dynamic programming and eliminate recursion altogether.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive formula is:

[image]

Now, expand the formula and using the mathematical induction:

[image]

As for `i=1`, we have constant time computation, we suppose `T(1) = 1`. Therefore:

[image]